# Data from localDB to mvc controller

Tags: .net, database

I'm trying to get data from a LocalDb into my MVC Controller. I tried this:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult List(string categoryName)
{
    var category = db.category.Include("Item").Where(k => k.Name.ToUpper() == categoryName.ToUpper()).Single();
    var temp = category.Name.ToList();
    return View(temp);
}
```

DAL

```
public class DB : DbContext
{
    public DB() : base("DB") { }
    static DB()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DB>(new DBInitializer());
    }
    public DbSet<Item> item { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> category { get; set; }
}
```

code of local db:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Item
{
    public virtual Category category { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string NameItem { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfAdding { get; set; }
    public string NameImage { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and i get exception in controller:

```
var category = db.category.Include("Item").Where(k => k.Name.ToUpper() == categoryName.ToUpper()).Single();
```

My idea is simple. When i click on "procesor" on my site i want see 2 position form my localDB - intel and AMD. Any sugestions how to fix that? Sorry for my poor english :P

Exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: „A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'ProjektNET1.DAL.Category' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Item'.”

Comment: Can you share the exception details ?

Comment: Added at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can join two tables like this. `TableA join TableB on TableA.column = TableB.Column.` This is very similar to the actual SQL foreign-key joins. Besides, if your localDB is actually a database, you don't need to convert uppercase. SQL is case-insensitive. You can use `string.equals(Otherstring, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

I don't understand how your table relationship works, below code joins both tables via CategoryId and selects Category.Name as list. like you tried in your code.

```
var Model = (from C in db.category
                join I in db.Item on C.CategoryId == I.CategoryId
                where 
                    C.Name == categoryName
                select 
                   C.Name
               ).ToList();

    return View(Model);
```